# Why is thecoolant leaking out after hitting the brakes hard

Tags: ford, brakes, radiator, water-pump, transit

My car was being driven erratically and the brakes were hit hard now I have coolant pouring out from somewhere under the radiator reservoir

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question? What have you done to pinpoint where the leak occurring? How much coolant is coming out? Is the vehicle overheating?

Comment: It sounds like someone else was driving your vehicle. Did they also drive over a curb or hit something and not tell you?

Answer (score 0):

A leak is going to be a hole, a failed gasket/o-ring, cracked fitting, popped off hose, etc. You need to actually look at the failure point.

You also have no vehicle age info. If it is older, and a fitting is corroded, hard braking which moves the engine forward hard... with worn mounts, forward harded. This can put pressure on the corroded fitting and cause it to fail.

I had my van on the hoist and my arm up reaching for trans cooler pipe which had failed. My arm was lightly pressing against a coolant hose and suddenly green flooding everywhere. That slight pressure was enough to break the fitting. You likely have similar if an older vehicle in the rust belt.

If not, it could be a plastic fitting flexed and snapped in same way.

If you are fortunate you had a hose which was not on securely and popped off.